# How to set proxy configuration of SVK

Tags: proxy, tortoisesvn, svk

I'm working behind a proxy, and now I'm trying to mirror a remote subversion repository, then got `could not connect to server` error with the `svn mirror` command.

I found the following on `svk` faq page:

> Currently svk doesn't have its own configuration file. however it loads the one that subversion uses, which should be ~/.subversion/servers. It will be created after the first time you run svn

BUT I just used the `tortoiseSVN` as my `svn client`, and there is no `/.subversion/servers` in my user `dir`.

How can I setup the proxy configuration in my situation?

Answer (score 0):

Create the file manually. From [this oracle page on svn proxy settings](http://blogs.oracle.com/venu/entry/svn_proxy_settings):

Create a text file `~/.subversion/servers` (Linux) or `%HOME%\.subversion\servers`

Add these two lines:

```
http-proxy-host = xxx.xxx.xxx.com
http-proxy-port = 8080
```

Fill in the correct values for your proxy.